# java output List with toString

Tags: java

My class having field is List<>, I went output tostring method

```
private String subjectCode;
private Long clientSn;
private Long ruleId;
private String beginDate;
private List<LessonPreferenceItemDTO> classPlans;
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "LessonPreferenceSaveReqDTO{" +
            "subjectCode='" + subjectCode + '\'' +
            ", clientSn=" + clientSn +
            ", ruleId=" + ruleId +
            ", beginDate='" + beginDate + '\'' +
            ", classPlans=" + classPlans +
            '}';
}
```

But, classPlans outout is java entity,don't LessonPreferenceItemDTO field info,So,How was output classPlans in this toString()

Comment: Did you implement `toString()` in LessonPreferenceItemDTO?

Comment: yes,  LessonPreferenceItemDTO is son class,I want output this field,I thinking useing for each,but,That's complicated

Comment: Please just provide the concrete output too and the code which makes the `System.out.println` call (and the variables used in the call)

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `public String toString()` for `LessonPreferenceItemDTO` as well. You may give *Apache Commons*
 [ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) a try if you like to output every property.

The class `ArrayList` for instance will render itself by surrounding its elements with `{` and `}` and separating the elements contained by `,` calling `toString()` of each contained element.

If you don't like the resulting format of `List.toString()` you have to serialize the list by yourself while iterating over each element.

Comment: I think just overriding the toString will not suffice his requirements right? he has to call that toString() method. correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Neeraj Jain: what I meant is to provide a proper `toString()` implementation for `LessonPreferenceItemDTO` as he did for the type `LessonPreferenceSaveReqDTO`. As he knew how to do it for `LessonPreferenceSaveReqDTO` he should knoiw how to provide one for `LessonPreferenceItemDTO`, or did I missed something? The `toString()` of `List` may be sufficient for him, because it will call `toString()` of its elements and add `{` and `,` and `}`.

Comment: I know, but want find simple for list tostring,rather than for each element,I think is very complexity for my code

Comment: @Richardli: if you want a proper output for one instance of `LessonPreferenceSaveReqDTO` you have to either implement it by yourself or try using [ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `toString()` method in `LessonPreferenceItemDTO` class but that's not all after that you need to call `toString()` on each element of this list.

You can use Java 8 stream API for that

```
classPlans.stream()
.map(LessonPreferenceItemDTO::toString) 
.collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return "LessonPreferenceSaveReqDTO{" +
            "subjectCode='" + subjectCode + '\'' +
            ", clientSn=" + clientSn +
            ", ruleId=" + ruleId +
            ", beginDate='" + beginDate + '\'' +
            ", classPlans=" + classPlans.stream().map(LessonPreferenceItemDTO::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
            '}';
}
```

I success output wants,use java 8 stream,very thanks@Harmlezz@Neeraj Jain